# How to disable DELETE button in VIEW?

Tags: views

I am using the View in my project with DELETE button (Configure field: Bulk operations: Content).

View has some important details,

How to disable the DELETE button except the admin?

Comment: If a user doesn't have permission to delete nodes they won't be able to. or are you talking about the view itself?

Comment: How to restrict the Permission (to disable DELETE button) for "anonymous user"?
PS: The Views delete button Created using "Configure field: Bulk operations: Content"